# Specifying options to map2() using a formula (rather than a function)

Tags: r, iteration, purrr

Say for instance I'm trying to use purrr::map2() to iterate rnorm() over a vector and I want to specify the options **n** and **sd** but not **mean**.

Using the "formula" way, I could do this:

```
len <- c(1, 3, 10); sigma <- c(1, 1, 10)
set.seed(123)
map2(len, sigma, ~rnorm(n = .x, sd = .y))
```

But is it possible to specify **n** and **sd** without specifying **mean** with the "function" way? If I do the following, it fills "sigma" in for **mean** because **mean** is the next option in rnorm() after **n**.

```
set.seed(123)
map2(len, sigma, rnorm)
```

I could specify that **mean** is 0 so that "sigma" would apply to **sd**, as below:

```
set.seed(123)
map2(len, sigma, rnorm, mean = 0)
```

But what if I wanted to leave **mean** at its default (without specifying it) and still have "sigma" apply to **sd**? As in, is there a way to do something like .x/.y if I'm using the "function" method.

Sorry that was wordy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah that is (editing my original Q to make that clearer), but I appreciate it. It's easy enough in this example, but for more complex functions I'd prefer not listing every option before the one I'm trying to get to. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because you have to manually direct the data to parameters other than the first one[s]. This is one of the advantages of base R's `Map`, which can take named parameters for iteration:

```r
library(purrr)

len <- c(1, 3, 10) 
sigma <- c(1, 1, 10)

set.seed(123)
map2(len, sigma, ~rnorm(n = .x, sd = .y)) %>% str()
#> List of 3
#>  $ : num -0.56
#>  $ : num [1:3] -0.2302 1.5587 0.0705
#>  $ : num [1:10] 1.29 17.15 4.61 -12.65 -6.87 ...

set.seed(123)
Map(rnorm, n = len, sd = sigma) %>% str()
#> List of 3
#>  $ : num -0.56
#>  $ : num [1:3] -0.2302 1.5587 0.0705
#>  $ : num [1:10] 1.29 17.15 4.61 -12.65 -6.87 ...
```

You can't do the same thing in `map2` because the input parameters are named `.x` and `.y`, whereas `Map` slurps up all the parameters in `...`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, aside from using `Map`, is to use `pmap`. This requires that you have your inputs in a list though.

```
set.seed(123)
a <- map2(len, sigma, ~rnorm(n = .x, sd = .y))

set.seed(123)
input <- list(n = len, sd = sigma)
b <- pmap(input, rnorm)

identical(a, b)
# [1] TRUE
```